# Move element to under finger, then make draggable with same action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, touch

On touchstart and mouse down, I want to move an element to under my finger or cursor, then be able to drag it.

js:

```
$('.matiMarker').draggable();
$('.matiValMarker').bind("mousedown touchstart",function(e){ 

    var that = this,
    $(this).parent().find('.matiMarker').animate({
        left : $(that).position().left + "px"
    },100);
});
```

So that will move the .matiMarker under my finger/cursor, and what I need to happen is to have that same mousedown/touchstart event to be the start of a drag. I'm lost as to how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Drag your element along mouse click start and end.</title>
<style type="text/css"><!--
#dg {
 width:180px;
 height:100px;
 margin:8px;
 background:#a7daa8;
 cursor:pointer;
}
--></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.14.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
//This variables stores your element's x and y position.
var xpos; var ypos;
//This method runs when your page is load.
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#matiMarker').draggable({
    // get the initial X and Y position when dragging starts
    start: function(event, ui) {
      xpos = ui.position.left;
      ypos = ui.position.top;
    },
    // when dragging stops
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      // your draggable element's current position.
      var xmove = ui.position.left;
      var ymove = ui.position.top;
    }
  });
});
--></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="matiMarker">Click and Drag<br />
Your element which has matiMarker id. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this way u can do drag and move actions on same function (start and stop function).